# iOS - WebRTC front camera - video is flipped horizontally

Tags: ios, webrtc, flip, front-camera

WebRTC video is flipped horizontally in Front Camera, thus in the receiving end also this flipped video is showing. But the Back Camera working fine as the Camera APP.

How to change this flipped behaviour of front camera and thus the captured frame which is receiving in the remote end?

Answer (score 4):

Please try the code.It means Flip Horizontal.It works for me.

```
self.localView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
```